# INSERT using PDO does not insert values

Tags: php, pdo

I need a mechanism that inserts the data from a newly registered user to a database. I use PDO to do this, and this is my current code:

```
$dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****', *****, *****);

$insert_query = $dbc->prepare('INSERT INTO members(name, gender, email, pass)   
VALUES(:name, :gender, :email, :pass) WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1');

$insert_query->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':gender' =>    
$gender, ':email' => $email,  ':pass' => $pass));
```

However, nothing happens when a user submits the register form. I tried to echo `$gender, $name, $email` and `$pass`, and they all showed correct values. I am new to PDO, and I'm not sure what the problem could be at all. Is it a syntax error of some sort, or is it something else?

I don't receive any error messages.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Wrong, he does.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I believe it accepts them with or without the `:`.  I always use them.

Comment: In the PHP documentation all the named parameters are with `:`.
@DannyCruzeira, have you tested any Db error? (Missing table, wrong field names...?)

Comment: But that's how they do it on [NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/), how are you then supposed to identify the array names afterwards?

Comment: Woah, Michael's right... there a LIMIT with an INSERT, it has no sense.

Comment: @Cranio, yes I have. Are there any way to check for errors automatically, like the mysql_error() or something similar?

Comment: I deleted the LIMIT part, still not working though.. It drives me nuts!

Comment: You do not do any error checking. Do error checking first when you think something is not alright.

Comment: @DannyCruzeira You also have an invalid and uncessary `WHERE` clause in there.

Comment: @DannyCruzeira I'm curious now if this was supposed to be an INSERT to begin with? Are you actually adding a new row, or are you attempting to update an existing row?

Comment: @Michael, it is meant to be an INSERT statement, since the row doesn't exist before. If it wasn't clear in the question I meant that the function should add values that a user typed in in a register form into the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe it is valid to include a `LIMIT` clause in an `INSERT` statement.  `LIMIT` is not among the optional clauses [in the MySQL `INSERT` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

You also have a `WHERE` clause, which is also invalid in an `INSERT` statement.

I suspect you don't have error reporting turned on, since this ought to have been a fatal error or thrown an exception if the statement failed to `prepare()` due to syntax errors. You would have gotten an error similar to

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1'

```
$insert_query = $dbc->prepare('INSERT INTO members(name, gender, email, pass)   
VALUES(:name, :gender, :email, :pass) WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1');
//------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

By definition, an `INSERT` statement inserts exactly as many rows as you have `()` groups<sup>*</sup> for in your `VALUES ()`, so there's no need for a `LIMIT` anyway. You could use a `LIMIT` in an `INSERT INTO...SELECT...` statement, but in that case, the `LIMIT` is a clause of the `SELECT` component rather than the `INSERT`.

<sup>*</sup> *Ignoring potential key violations or other insert problems, obviously*

The fact that you have conflated multiple components (`WHERE,LIMIT`) from `UPDATE` statements makes me wonder if you actually intended this to be an `UPDATE` rather than an `INSERT` statement to begin with.  `INSERT` is only for *new rows*.  `UPDATE` is for changing existing rows, and both `WHERE` and `LIMIT` are valid in `UPDATE`.

That would look like:

```
$upd_query = $dbc->prepare('UPDATE members SET name = :name, gender = :gender, email = :email, pass = :pass) WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1');
```

Comment: No, it is meant to be an INSERT statement, since the row doesn't exist before. If it wasn't clear in the question I meant that the function should add values that a user typed in in a register form into the database.

Answer (score 1):

As "Michael" said, you can't use `LIMIT n` in an `INSERT` query.

After all, You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement.

Comment: You can, for emulated prepares and some recent PHP versions. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48856

Comment: @hakra Well, I believe that a bug, is a bug!

Answer (score 1):

Try swtching to `UPDATE` query syntax. Looks to be what you need.